# Regex in Visual Studio find and replace not working

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Trying to use Find and Replace in Visual Studio 2017.

It's seemingly working perfectly on a Regex checking tool that is online but not working in Visual Studio when I do a Find search (Ctrl + F).

Any ideas why this may be? Do I need to do anything differently in VS compared to the standard Regex?

Here is the Regex:

```
([.material\-icons]+[a-z|A-Z|\-|\_]+:+before,)
```

Here is a sample set of code/text:

```
.material-icons.three-d-rotation:before,
.icon-mi-three-d-rotation:before {
    content: '\e84d';
}

.material-icons.ac-unit:before,
.icon-mi-ac-unit:before {
    content: '\eb3b';
}
```

It is supposed to find

> .material-icons.three-d-rotation:before,

and

> .material-icons.ac-unit:before,

Comment: You must remove the backslash before `_`, `\_` makes the .NET regex syntax invalid. Use `\.material-icons\.[\w.-]+:+before,`

Comment: Works! Can you make that an answer please? I'll accept it. Thank you!! :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove the backslash before `_`, `\_` makes the .NET regex syntax invalid.

Also, if you need to match a sequence of chars and not chars in any other order and any amount, you should use a mere sequence of those chars without putting them into a character class. Change `[.material\-icons]+` into `\.material-icons`.

Note that `-` outside of a character class (outside of `[...]`) does not need escaping.

Inside a character class, `|` matches a pipe char, it is not an OR operator. Thus, you should remove it from the `[...]`.

There is no need wrapping the whole pattern with parentheses, if you need to replace with the whole match, use the `$&` placeholder.

You may use

```
\.material-icons\.[\w.-]+:+before,
```

[image]

**Details**

- `\.material-icons\.` - a literal `.material-icons.` text
- `[\w.-]+` -  1 or more letters, digits, `_`, `.` or `-`
- `:+` - 1+ colons
- `before,` - a literal substring.

Comment: 10 minutes before I can accept that as an answer haha!

Comment: @Imdad Please see the details I have added, these clarifications should help you to further streamline your regexps.

Comment: Cheers mate - great help!

Comment: I'm having a problem with the `$&` replacement pattern. Instead of getting the matched sequence from the "Find what" box, it is replacing with the literal `$&` sequence. (VS 2017, Quick Replace, RegEx enabled - though the "Find what" could be found with enabling RegEx)

Comment: @Zarepheth Did you check the regex mode option? The `.*` one.

Comment: I turned off the RegEx, no difference in results. Turned it back on, no difference - still acted like RegEx was off. Then I just stopped fighting VS and surrounded my "Find what" text with parenthesis and replaced `$&` with `$1` to get the desired result. :(

Comment: @Zarepheth In my VS2017, `\.material-icons\.[\w.-]+:+before,` => `"&$"` works fine. Other options - Match whole word and Match case - must be OFF.

Comment: Further testing, if my "Find what" is wrapped in parenthesis, `$&` works correctly. If not, it fails.